# Dumping a core and terminating a process using SIGSEGV or SIGABRT signals

Tags: c++, c, posix

Current Implementation of my process,

If there is a logic error in the process, it will dumb the core and quit by deliberately accessing invalid memory area. (sending SIGSEGV signal)

```
 char* pzCoreMsg = "Logic Error";
 char* zTmp = NULL;
 strcpy(zTmp, pzCoreMsg);
```

Other Possible Implementations

1) Calling `raise(SIGABRT)` function is also a possible solution. (sending SIGABRT signal)

2) It is also possible to call  `abort()` function (sending SIGABRT signal)

There may be many more solutions exist. I want to get to know the best method to dumb the core and terminate a process

Comment: Calling [`abort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/abort.html) is the usual way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on undefined behavior, just call [`abort()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html). It will raise SIGABRT and dump core by default. `abort()` will also unblock SIGABRT, and if the signal is ignored (or if the signal handler returns), it will restore the default disposition and raise it again.  There's really no need to do anything further.